# Finding a point in a convex polygon farthest to an external point

Tags: geometry, algorithms, convex-analysis, polygons, computational-geometry

> Given a point $q$ external to a convex polygon $P$, propose an algorithm to compute a farthest point in $P$ to $q$.

---

One can always have at least one vertex of $P$ in the set of farthest points of $P$ to $q$. So a linear algorithm is possible, computing for each vertex its distance to $q$. I wonder if a faster algorithm is possible. Initially I thought so, but I am now more enclined to try and prove that such algorithm is $\Omega (n)$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2848232/339790)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- If the vertices are sorted by angle (azimuth) from any interior point (e.g. the [centeroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid)), you can achieve $O(\log n)$.
- If the vertices are in any order, in the worst case you will need $\Omega(n)$ checks.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Let's assume the vertices are sorted. If I consider one point and its two neighbours, compputing for each the distance to $q$, four cases may happen, depending on the order of the distances. In each case I can delete at least $\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor $ vertices. This leads to a  $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ running time. But I am not sure it works...

Comment: @peter It depends on how you implement it, but if I understood your solution correctly, it should work. However, I have advice and a hint: first, try to build your algorithm from bigger blocks, its easier; second, have you heard of binary search?

Comment: Thank you for your hints and advice. Yes this new algorithm relies on binary search. I am not sure I understand what you mean with bigger blocks though.

Comment: @peter I just meant using other algorithms/concepts (like binary search) as subprocedures, rather than doing everything from scratch. My algorithm was to assign to each edge a number: $1$ if sorting direction and farther-from-$q$-direction coincide and $0$ otherwise; then, your input looks like [00011111111111110000] and it's enough to (binary)search for $1$-to-$0$ transition.

Comment: @dtldarek I cannot understand why you are able to use binary search to find 1-0 in such array?

Comment: @SavinovEvgeny You can do it if you have the index of at least one zero and one 1, the problem would be only if you have something like [00000010000] but you don't know where 1 is. Besides this input would actually be the cosine of angle between vectors (from scalar product) which is non-constant unless you allow for degenerated cases (like multiple collinear points), but even then you can use angle as seen from the centeroid to break ties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking here in terms of a strategy where you spend time analyzing the polygon, then run many queries on many points $q$, so you want to optimize the time per $q$.  It would be different if you were given many polygons and only wanted to test one point per polygon.

Let $R_{a,b}$ be the half-plane where point $a$ is farther than point $b$.  Then $\bigcap_{i \neq a} R_{a,i}$ is the convex region where point a is farther than all other points.

So you can calculate a partition of the plane into $n$ convex regions.  Then your problem becomes finding which convex region the query point $q$ falls within, and that can be done with a binary tree in $O(\log n)$ time.

Answer (score 0):

A general algorithm which is faster than O(n) is not possible. To see why, consider a regular polygon of any number of vertices, and a query point $q$ at its center. Each vertex of this polygon is now equally far from $q$, and these are the farthest points. We can now take any vertex $v_i$ and move it slightly away from $q$, such that the farthest point is now strictly this vertex, and we can do this without breaking convexity. All other vertices remain the same.

The fact that this is possible means that it's always necessary to check all vertices. It's not possible with this polygon to take a subset of the vertices, perform some test on this subset, and based on the outcome of that test conclude that a larger range which includes vertices not in this subset can't contain the farthest point. For example, if the subset does not include vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$, then we can never use this subset to distinguish between cases where $v_i$ vs $v_j$ was moved.

The same idea also works when $q$ has to be external to the convex polygon. Simply take the half of the regular polygon formed by the vertices strictly above a horizontal line through $q$.